# Angular http request has two calls on network tab. Is it ok?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I was looking to my http requests on the browser's network tab and I see I have two rows for each call. I don't understand why is it happening and if it is ok.

In the back end I can see that one of the calls is of type OPTIONS and the other of type GET.

FUNCTION TO CALL THE GETUSUARIOX

```
getUsuarios() {
const users$= this.http.get<HttpResponses>(this.apiUrl + 'getUsuariox').pipe(shareReplay());
users$.subscribe(res=>{
  this.dataUsuarios = res;
  this.dataUsuarios$.next(res.data);
})
  return users$;
```

}

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I have just realized that the call made with the OPTION method comes from the http interceptor which is adding the token to all http requests. Is it right how it is working?

Comment: Thank you Jason. English is not my first language. I'll pay more attention in future questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

The first request is a [Pre-flight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

From the docs:

> A CORS preflight request is a CORS request that checks to see if the
> CORS protocol is understood and a server is aware using specific
> methods and headers.
>
> It is an OPTIONS request, using three HTTP request headers:
> `Access-Control-Request-Method`, `Access-Control-Request-Headers`, and the
> `Origin` header.

It is *not* added by the Angular HTTP Interceptor. It is automatically added by the browser to ensure the server abides CORS and allows the user-agent (the browser) to make the actual request.

Comment: I have just read the documentation. Thank you very much for your help.